# Can apt show command say if package is installed in OS?

Tags: apt

Command

```
apt show packagename
```

shows info about packagename, if it was found,
But can this command (or some other) also show if packagename is installed now?
2) From which repository it was installed?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd likely use `apt-cache policy` to see what sources currently enabled provide the package in question, plus what version of package I'm currently using (*or that none are installed*)

Answer (score 10):

I'd likely use `apt-cache policy` to see what sources currently enabled provide the package in question, plus what version of package I'm currently using (*or that none are installed*)

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: 1.488
  Candidate: 1.488
  Version table:
 *** 1.488 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.487 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic/main amd64 Packages
```

@Raffa suggests `apt show` which

> will actually show an extra line when a package is installed like
> "*APT-Manual-Installed: yes*"

with the same results on my box looking like

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$    apt show ubuntu-desktop
Package: ubuntu-desktop
Version: 1.488
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Source: ubuntu-meta
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Installed-Size: 54.3 kB
Provides: packagekit-installer
Depends: alsa-base, alsa-utils, anacron, at-spi2-core, bc, ca-certificates, dmz-cursor-theme, fonts-dejavu-core, fonts-freefont-ttf, foomatic-db-compressed-ppds, gdm3, ghostscript-x, gnome-control-center, gnome-menus, gnome-session-canberra, gnome-settings-daemon, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension-appindicator, gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng, gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock, gstreamer1.0-alsa, gstreamer1.0-packagekit, gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps, inputattach, language-selector-common, language-selector-gnome, libatk-adaptor, libnotify-bin, libsasl2-modules, libu2f-udev, nautilus, openprinting-ppds, pipewire-pulse, printer-driver-pnm2ppa, rfkill, software-properties-gtk, spice-vdagent, ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-drivers-common, ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk, ubuntu-session, ubuntu-settings, unzip, update-manager, update-notifier, wireless-tools, wireplumber, wpasupplicant, xdg-user-dirs, xdg-user-dirs-gtk, xkb-data, xorg, yelp, zenity, zip
Recommends: aisleriot, apport-gtk, appstream, apt-config-icons-hidpi, avahi-autoipd, avahi-daemon, baobab, bluez, bluez-cups, branding-ubuntu, brltty, cheese, cups, cups-bsd, cups-client, cups-filters, deja-dup, dirmngr, eog, evince, file-roller, fonts-indic, fonts-kacst-one, fonts-khmeros-core, fonts-lao, fonts-liberation, fonts-liberation2, fonts-lklug-sinhala, fonts-noto-cjk, fonts-noto-color-emoji, fonts-opensymbol, fonts-sil-abyssinica, fonts-sil-padauk, fonts-thai-tlwg, fonts-tibetan-machine, fonts-ubuntu, fwupd, fwupd-signed, gamemode, gir1.2-gmenu-3.0, gnome-accessibility-themes, gnome-bluetooth, gnome-calculator, gnome-calendar, gnome-characters, gnome-disk-utility, gnome-font-viewer, gnome-initial-setup, gnome-keyring, gnome-logs, gnome-mahjongg, gnome-mines, gnome-power-manager, gnome-remote-desktop, gnome-sudoku, gnome-system-monitor, gnome-terminal, gnome-text-editor, gnome-todo, gpg-agent, gsettings-ubuntu-schemas, gvfs-fuse, hplip, ibus, ibus-gtk, ibus-gtk3, ibus-table, im-config, kerneloops, laptop-detect, libglib2.0-bin, libnss-mdns, libpam-fprintd, libpam-gnome-keyring, libpam-sss, libproxy1-plugin-gsettings, libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-gnome, libreoffice-impress, libreoffice-math, libreoffice-ogltrans, libreoffice-pdfimport, libreoffice-style-breeze, libreoffice-writer, libspa-0.2-bluetooth, libwmf0.2-7-gtk, memtest86+, mousetweaks, nautilus-sendto, nautilus-share, network-manager, network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu, network-manager-openvpn-gnome, network-manager-pptp-gnome, orca, packagekit, pcmciautils, plymouth-theme-spinner, policykit-desktop-privileges, printer-driver-brlaser, printer-driver-c2esp, printer-driver-foo2zjs, printer-driver-m2300w, printer-driver-min12xxw, printer-driver-ptouch, printer-driver-pxljr, printer-driver-sag-gdi, printer-driver-splix, remmina, rhythmbox, seahorse, shotwell, simple-scan, snapd, speech-dispatcher, system-config-printer, systemd-oomd, thunderbird, thunderbird-gnome-support, totem, transmission-gtk, ubuntu-docs, ubuntu-report, ubuntu-wallpapers, usb-creator-gtk, whoopsie, xcursor-themes, xdg-desktop-portal-gnome, xdg-utils, yaru-theme-gnome-shell, yaru-theme-gtk, yaru-theme-icon, yaru-theme-sound
Download-Size: unknown
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: /var/lib/dpkg/status
Description: The Ubuntu desktop system
 This package depends on all of the packages in the Ubuntu desktop system
 .
 It is also used to help ensure proper upgrades, so it is recommended that
 it not be removed.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

Comment: fyi:  the spaces before the command are just so that command doesn't get stored in my `.bash_history` ... I don't want it cluttered up with stuff I do for others...   There are of course alternate commands, but it's my usual first choice.

Comment: It might be worth noting as well that `apt show package-name` will actually show an extra line when a package is installed like `APT-Manual-Installed: yes` ... That line is, however, absent when the package is not installed.

Comment: you can use `dpkg -s $PACKAGE_NAME`. which lists info about the  package (and returns 0) if it is installed. If it is not installed (or doesn't exist,) it return 0

Comment: … and the “APT-Manual-Installed” will say “no“ if the package wasn’t manually installed (*i.e.* it was installed automatically).